# How to complete a svn commit process inside the terminal?

Tags: linux, svn, vim

I am a begineer at using svn and linux. I want to remove the test files from the repository URL. These files were added by the import command. Now when I remove these files from the local svn dir using the `svn delete` command, it is done successfully. Now its time to perform the commit, here lies the problem,I enter the svn commit command and it displays the list of all the actions that need to be performed during the commit. Files which are to be added or deleted or whatever action has to be done. I get stuck here and I do not know what to do to complete the commit.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `svn commit` starts an editor where you can enter your commit message. After you entered the message, save and exit, and the commit is completed. If you exit without entering anything, Subversion will ask if you want to abort the commit or get back to editing the message.

Your screenshot looks like `vim`, the most awesomest editor for hackers. Press the `i` key to enter into editing mode, enter your text, then press `Escape` to get out of editing mode (back to command mode), and type `:wq` to save the file and exit (w = write, q = quit).

If you don't want Subversion to launch an editor when committing, you can enter the commit message on the command line, for example:

```
svn commit -m 'deleted junk'
```

This has the same effect as running `svn commit`, entering "deleted junk", and save and exit. The downside of this is that with this method you don't see the list of files that will be committed, which can be useful to avoid mistaken commits.